# Is there a way to analyse a video to find out its loudness and then correct it to ebu r128

Tags: windows, audio, video, ffmpeg

I wanted to see if anyone know the best way I can analyse a audio of a video and find out it's loudness.

I want to use this information to then correct the audio either through FFmpeg or other means.
The audio has to met https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/r/r128.pdf the ebu standard of loudness -23 and not higher than 0.5.

is there a way to do this?

I am having difficulties finding a solution.

Comment: ffmpeg document is pretty good https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Python package that I wrote called [`ffmpeg-normalize`](https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize/). It uses the built-in `loudnorm` filter but adds some convenience methods. Please have a look at the README.

```
$ pip install --user ffmpeg-normalize
```

To get the loudness statistics in JSON format, zse `-p` and `-n` (dry run):

```
$ ffmpeg-normalize BigBuckBunny.avi -p -n
[
    {
        "input_file": "BigBuckBunny.avi",
        "output_file": "normalized/BigBuckBunny.mkv",
        "stream_id": 1,
        "ebu": {
            "input_i": "-32.25",
            "input_tp": "-8.70",
            "input_lra": "20.60",
            "input_thresh": "-44.86",
            "output_i": "-23.26",
            "output_tp": "-2.00",
            "output_lra": "11.40",
            "output_thresh": "-33.80",
            "normalization_type": "dynamic",
            "target_offset": "0.26"
        },
        "mean": null,
        "max": null
    }
]
```

To run the normalization on the audio stream and copy the video over:

```
ffmpeg-normalize BigBuckBunny.avi -c:a aac -b:a 192k
```

This will write the file to `normalized/BigBuckBunny.mkv` and re-encode the audio stream with ffmpeg's internal AAC encoder. To change the output filename, use `-o`.

Comment: is there a way to do this to video files. I have mxf video files, that has to also output back to mxf

Comment: how can i specify the location of where to drop the file and its format. would im trying with ```-of C:/APerson/Desktop -o new.mxf``` but get conversion failed

Comment: Just specify the complete output path with `-o`. If you get any errors, please provide the full log (e.g. copy to pastebin). The output format is automatically set via the file extension (just like in ffmpeg).

Comment: "only 48khz is implemented" – try adding `-ar 48000` to the command options.

Comment: Check if `ffmpeg -i input.mxf -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 48000 -map 0 output.mxf` works. If not, it's an upstream issue and has nothing to do with the particular question here. In that case, please ask a new question on [SU], [video.SE] or the ffmpeg-user mailing list.

Comment: that command works: ```ffmpeg -i input.mxf -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 48000 -map 0 output.mxf```

Comment: You used `pcm_s32le` in your command, not `aac` as suggested in my example. This is apparently not supported. The error is misleading. Use `pcm_s24le` and `-ar 48000` instead.

Comment: i did the same code as suggested with ``pcm-s24le``` this also works.

Comment: so i finally managed to get mxf output 
```ffmpeg-normalize VOx1.mxf -c:v copy -ar 48000 -c:a pcm_s24le -o file.mxf```
however, upon analysing the audio, the output is 23.4 not 23

Comment: Could be a bug in the `loudnorm` filter in upstream ffmpeg. I suggest creating a short example to verify. Of course I wouldn't expect 100% accuracy.